# Using rc.local to start network dependent services

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, networking, docker, centos

Is it safe to use /etc/rc.local to initialize services that depend on the network?

I'm using it to start a service that makes some requests to the network during its startup process. Happens that occasionally the service startup is failing (not all the times).

This is the error I'm getting:

`2016-06-07T12:01:48.724+0000 W NETWORK [ReplicationExecutor] getaddrinfo("my_machine_local_dns") failed: Name or service not known`

When it fails, if I try to initialize the service manually after the machine boot is complete, there are no errors.

I'm thinking about any racing conditions. Example: when it fails is because the service starts before the network is completed loaded or something like that.

I'm using centos inside a aws vpc, and the service in question is running inside a docker container.

Comment: Is your Centos in Private Subnet or public Subnet in the VPC?

Answer (score 1):

Your service fails at startup because your instance is in a Private subnet. Instances in private subnet do not have internet connection till they are fully created. Once instance is fully created in a Private Subnet it is then they start talking to the NAT instance and then get the internet connection . Thats why it fails when you run it at the startup.

> Is it safe to use /etc/rc.local to initialize services that depend on
>   the network?

/usr/local/ is really the right place, while /opt is really for third party applications; "/opt is reserved for the installation of add-on application software packages." As per the best practice goes.

Comment: In this case the instance is already created and the error is happening on the instance restart process. Is this also the case? Also, this explains why it happens occasionally and not all the times?

Comment: Yes this is the case when you restart the Instance in private subnet.

Comment: Any recommendations on where should be a good place to put those kind of scripts instead of rc.local?

Comment: I did not get your question?

Comment: The service startup is failing because it is on rc.local and at that point the instance doesn't have network connection. Where should be a safe place to put the service initialization script? /etc/init.d/ ?